# Table of Contents Modification: How to change fonts from bold to normal?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I am writing my dissertation and for that, I am using a style file that originally was created by Georgia Tech, but later on, it was modified by different students at my school. The problem I currently have is that our school has recently changed some of their standards for the format of a dissertation. I have been able to modify this style file accordingly to cover most of their changes. However, there is one thing I haven't been able to figure out so far and that is: Right now, the style file generates a table of contents where each chapter title is shown in bold (please look at the image). Our school requires that nothing should be in bold for this section. Please provide advice if you know how to fix this. I would be more than happy to share the style file or discuss this in private with you.

[image: table of contents sample figure]

Comment: Edit your `cls` file and look for the command `\tableofcontents`. You'll be able to understand what is happening there.

Comment: The only part that I see in the cls file that is releavant is the following:\newcommand{\settocstring}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\gtcontentsname}{#1}
%  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\Makeuppercase{#1}}  %RSS
 \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\  \vspace{0.5in}  \\ \Makeuppercase{#1}} %RSS
  \renewcommand{\toccontentlinestring}{%
    \texorpdfstring{\Makeuppercase{#1}}{#1}
  }
  \renewcommand{\tocpdfbookmarkstring}{#1}
}

Comment: It is difficulty to understand only with these parts since it is not the default.

Comment: I think it will be much easier when you just provide your document class file/package. Another possibility would be to change the look of the ToC with another package like `tocloft`, but I guess this is not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The part that is responsible for setting the chapters in the ToC is `\l@chapter` in the standard document classes. Take, for example, its definition from [`report.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls):

```
\newcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
```

Note how within the `\begingroup`...`\endgroup` segment, a number of lengths are set (`\parindent` is set to zero/`\z@`, `\rightskip` is set to `\@pnumwidth` and `\parfillskip` is set to `-\@pnumwidth`). Subsequently, horizontal mode is entered (`\leavevmode`) and then the font series is set to **bold** (`\bfseries`).

You'll probably find something similar in your class or style file which needs changing. This can either be achieved via a total redefinition, a temporary removal of the meaning of `\bfseries` or a patch (using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and friends).

---

[`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) is also an option, and allows for specific changes to ToC entries based on their level (chapter, or section, or subsection, ...).

Comment: Hi Werner and thank you for your answer. What you suggested worked! I just had to remove the \bfseries in the locations you suggested. There is one more issue left and that is I still have "Table of contents" and "List of Figures" in bold format. Could you please tell me where I have to remove the bold font function? I do appreciate your help and time.

Comment: @RamenZ: The ToC (and friends) are usually set as a regular `\chapter*`, which makes it a little more difficult; you don't want to change the definitions inside `\@chapter` or `\@schapter` (called by `\chapter`) since it could affect the remainder of your document. Perhaps an altogether easier approach is to use `{\let\bfseries\relax \tableofcontents \listoffigures \listoftables}`, which makes `\bfseries` a no-op temporarily...

Comment: Hi Werner thanks again. I will try this and see if it works. To be clear, I can add this line anywhere in the style file or should it be inside the \l@chapter section? If inside, again does it matter where?

Comment: @RamenZ: No, you would not add this to the style file; you'll just use it as-is in your document. For addition in your style file it would look something like `\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{{\let\bfseries\relax\oldtableofcontents}}`, and you would do something similar to `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`. You have to make sure that these redefinitions are placed *after* they are defined in your `.sty` though. However, as already mentioned, you can use what I suggested earlier as-is in your document.

Comment: Thanks Werner, I will try this shortly and let you know about the outcome. I really am thankful for your time and guidance.

Comment: Hi Werner, an update: Your first suggestion fixes that problem. However, it messes up the page numbering and provides incorrect numbers in the table of contents. Also after the list of tables and figures, there are two extra blank pages with the title "list of figures" and "list of tables" in bold font. Your second suggestion resolves the issue completely without causing these errors. Thanks again you really helped me a lot:)

Comment: Hi Werner, I am having two more issues with my dissertation style and I am hoping that you could please answer them:

 1. It seems that the font size of my Table of contents (and everything in this table) as well as my list of figures (and everything in it) is different than the standard followed in the rest of the preliminary sections. How would I change them and how would I know what the standard for the rest of the preliminary sections is?

Comment: 2. It seems that in all my chapters, the first paragraph of every section and subsection begins with no indent. How can I define them to all begin with an indent?